# Pushing attachments on loop defined ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a form that has a `+ ADD` button to dynamically add another form. inside each form it has two input as `co_number`, `attachments` i want to store each form on the MySQL via `axios` following is what i had tried and not working. is there any proper solution to fix this?

**TEMPLATE**

```
<template>
<div id="Tasks">
<v-row v-for="(i, k) in formList" :key="k">
  <v-col md="1" sm="3" cols="12">
    <!-- REMOVE ROW BUTTON -->
    <v-btn color="red" v-if="formList.length > 1" @click="remomvePOList(k)">
      <v-icon>
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <!-- ADD ROW BUTTON -->
    <v-btn
      color="blue"
      v-if="k == formList.length - 1"
      @click="addNewPO(k)"
    >
      <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-col>
  <v-col md="2" sm="3" cols="12" class="">
    <v-text-field v-model="i.co" label="CO Number" dense hide-details="">
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>

  <v-file-input
    v-model="i.attachments"
    multiple
    label="ATTACHMENTS"
    @change="onAttachmentSelected($event, k)"
  >
  </v-file-input>
  <v-btn @click="save">SAVE</v-btn>
</v-row>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formList: [{ co: "", attachments: [] }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewPO(e) {
      this.formList.push({
        co: "",
        attachments: [],
      });
    },
    remomvePOList(e) {
      this.formList.splice(e, 1);
    },
    onAttachmentSelected(e, k) {
      this.formList[k].attachments.push(e);
      // ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
    },
    save() {
      // axios post request
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** Objects represent “things” with characteristics (aka properties), while arrays create and store lists of data in a single variable. Both dot and bracket notation allow us to access, add, change, and remove items from an object, while zero-based indexing and a variety of built-in methods let us access and alter items in an array. Finally, we can iterate over object properties and array items using various loops (e.g. for, for…in, for…of, forEach())

```
onAttachmentSelected(e, k) {
  console.log('e',e)
  console.log('k',k)
  this.formList[k].attachments = Object.assign(e)
  console.log(this.formList)
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-file-input
    v-model="i.attachments"
    multiple
    label="ATTACHMENTS"
    @change="onAttachmentSelected($event, k)"
  >
  </v-file-input>
```

If `v-file-input` changes, `i.attachments` gets updated because it is bound to `v-model`.
However, `onAttachmentSelected` function changes `i.attachments` again which doesn't make sense.
What we have to bear in mind is the variable bound to the model automatically gets updated and we don't need to change the value in the event callback function.

From this idea, do we need to push `e` even if we remove one from `<v-file-input>`?

So just comment and make use of it without worring about updating
`this.formList[k].attachments` manually.

```
onAttachmentSelected(e, k) {
  // this.formList[k].attachments.push(e);
  // put rest functionalities here
}
```

Comment: the input `v-file-input` can be generated dynamically so `e` is needed to manage the array